# vb.net save datagridview to text file with delimiter

Tags: vb.net

how can i save cell values to text file with delimiter
i have 9 rows
and i have this code

```
Dim newoutputlines As New List(Of String)
Dim finlines As New List(Of String)
Dim aas As String = ""
For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    For v As Integer = 0 To 9
    'extracting cell value from 0 to 9 and add it on list
    newoutputlines.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(v).Value)
    Next
   'adding delimiter to list
    aas = String.Join("|", newoutputlines.ToArray())
    finlines.add(ass)
Next
IO.File.WriteAllLines(FILE_NAME, finlines.ToArray)
```

then on my text file i want to save like this format

```
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9 'this is from index 0 of gridview
0|3|0|8|6|5|6|7|8|0 'this is from index 1 of gridview
6|1|2|5|4|5|6|7|5|59 'this is from index 2 of gridview
```

but im failed
and the result i've got on my text file is like this

```
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0|3|0|8|6|5|6|7|8|0
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0|3|0|8|6|5|6|7|8|0|6|1|2|5|4|5|6|7|5|59
```

Comment: what failed? error message, exception type?

Comment: no vbnewline when saving to file

Comment: no does it automatically gave new line when write to text file.also on first loop it can get the index 0 and on second loop index 0 is still there with index 1, then on third loop 2 values is also get index 0 ,1,3

Comment: i wonder why every loop of (i) the list still collects every index and so on.sorry its hard to explain

Comment: Because your `newoutputlines` still have previuos lines

Comment: how can i fix this i already edited my post can you please recheck it thank you

Comment: i've got i by adding newoutputlines.Clear() inside the loop..thanks you so much fabio

Answer (score -1):

Your `newoutputlines` still have previous values. You need to clear it every time you add new row
But i want to show my approach to save values in the file by using `StringBuilder`. If you will have a lot of rows then this approach will be more efficient.

```
Dim text As New StringBuilder()
For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    For v As Integer = 0 To 9
        'extracting cell value from 0 to 9 and add it on list
        if v > 0 Then text.Append("|")
        text.Append(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(v).Value.ToString())
    Next
   'adding new line to text
    text.AppendLine()
Next
IO.File.WriteAllText(FILE_NAME, text.ToString())
```

Comment: hi fabio the problem in this code is it append delimiter in the beginning that i don't need it. anyway thank you for the help... adding newoutputlines.Clear() on my code works perfectly

Comment: @JuliusMalundras, delimeter will be added only after first item. There is condition `if v > 0 Then text.Append("|")`